# How to display My Events calendar?

Tags: calendar, filter, events

I have a calendar on SharePoint page where several people can add meetings and add attendees between them. No problem to show a calendar with a view for all the meetings.

However, I need everyone to be able to see "all meetings where I am an attendee".
View filter with "Attendees contain [Me]" is not possible to create.

It is in SharePoint 2013 so maybe JSLink would be helpful.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Doesn't it work if you create a view and do the Filter like this: Attendees is equal to [Me]?

Comment: No, it just returns nothing. I assume it is as there are more people than just one.

Comment: For me it works, but the column attendees is reserved. Maybe choose an other name.

Comment: It does, thank you very much. I was just login as another user. Feel free to  add this as an answer and I will +1

Comment: :D just did that. Didn't see the comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the steps I tried:

1. Add a calender to your page (I picked the name Calendar)

[image]

2. Create a new column

[image]

3. I picked the name Persons with the following settings. (Attendees was in my case already in use, because it belongs to the default columns)

[image]

4. Then I created a new view

[image]

5. Took the calendar view

[image]

6. And here are the filter options:

[image]

7. Then I created two items. One with me and someone else in the field. And a other one with only an other person in the column "Persons". The new view which is called my show only one item.

[image]

Comment: For me it worked simply with a filter "Attendees equal to [Me]"

Comment: That's correct, because Attendees is already a column if you create a new calender.